# Getting production organization ID from sandbox using API

Tags: soap-api, sandbox, production

Is there a queryable ressource through the API from a Salesforce sandbox instance that can return the related production environment organization ID?

Comment: An interesting related question. [The Sandbox creation process will replace occurrences of the production OrgId with the new Sandbox Id.](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/55757/102)

Comment: Related: [Can the production org id corresponding to a sandbox org id be found via Apex?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/20495/102)

Comment: if you are not building an appexchange package, then custom settings is a convenient workaround. the prod orgId should be invariant for the life of the org

Comment: This post is an old one, but i am answering in the hope that it might help someone searching for it. 1.Connect to the Prod org using SOAP API.2. Execute 'String soqlOrgId = 'Select Id from Organization';' .The result has the Id

Answer (score 2):

Got production org id by parsing Deployment Settings page right from apex code:

```
// get content of 'Deployment Connections' page from setup
String pageContent = new PageReference('/changemgmt/deploymentSettings.apexp').getContent().toString();

// regex to parse producion org id from html table markup
Pattern productionOrgIdRegEx = Pattern.compile('(?i)/changemgmt/deployConnectionDetailPage.apexp?id=(\\w+)');

Matcher matcher = productionOrgIdRegEx.matcher(pageContent);

String productionOrgId = 
    matcher.find() 
    ?
        matcher.group(1).trim()
        :
        null
;

System.assertEquals(
    null,
    productionOrgId
);
```

[image]

Comment: Just found this example as I need to get the production org. But is it the regexp correct? Because after matching I get null and in fact the System assert at the end checks for the Id to be null. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, the regexp that worked for me is 

Pattern productionOrgIdRegEx = Pattern.compile('(?i)\\/changemgmt\\/deployConnectionDetailPage.apexp\\?id=(\\w+)');

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is really an answer to the question as asked, but it is an effective workaround....

1. Create a Hierarchy Custom Setting called "Production Org Ids".
2. Add two custom fields, Org_Id_15_char__c, and Org_Id_18_char__c.
3. Populate the Default Organization Level Value with your Production Org Id's 15 and 18 character values.

*Why a custom setting?* So it gets faithfully re-created in your Sandbox, AND so you can populate the values using Apex in your unit tests.

*Why a Hierarchy type Custom Setting?* So it's available for Process Builder, Workflow Rules, and Formula fields.

I this is the basis of a design pattern I call "Instance Awareness". By comparing the Custom Setting to `UserInfo.getOrganizationId()` we can ascertain whether or not the code is running in a Production Org or not.

I use this technique to ensure that API calls made from a Sandbox don't ever go to a Production endpoint.