# How to get `parent` Org id for current Sandbox through api?

Tags: api, sandbox

In a case when I have creds only for Sandbox.

I do not found such api in documentation.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009ANxIAM ?

Comment: There is no direct way of finding a production org ID from a sandbox environment  as per my knowledge. Why don't you set the prod id as a custom setting and read it in sandbox since it is never going to change?

Comment: @glls thank you for link but this is not about how to get the id of *parent* Org

Comment: There is a potential solution to this [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/211319/17894)